# What happened to the Exocomps?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, sentience

In Star Trek, whatever happened to the exocomps?

[image: An excomp, looking like a mostly black faceted spheroid with blinking lights, silver details and a pair of large red pyramidal feet, hovers in the air in front of a vertically-mounted console. A cylindrical device on its "front" is projecting a blue beam that is triggering patterns of lines in the display.]

I recall that they were in an episode that showed them as sentient, but never saw them again.

Comment: Sent [down the mines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Author,_Author_(episode)#Act_Five) with all the leftover EMHs no doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: ["Exocomp", *Memory Alpha*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Exocomp)

It would seem they were promptly forgotten. Too bad, as they are a reference to one of my all-time-favorite Anime, [Dirty Pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Pair).

There are other examples of strange things gaining intelligence in the ST universe, a [list you can see here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lifeform#Other_types_of_life).

Some Highlights:

- [Horta](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Horta)
- [Microbrain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Microbrain)
- [Data](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data)
- The [Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emergence_%28episode%29)

Comment: Not like there was really any sensible way to bring them back. What would they do, follow Data around like a puppy?

Comment: @Xantec: Come back in a later episode as a civilization. Merge with the Borg. Assimilate the dominion. Come back to fight the Federation as mounts for cybernetic changelings.

Comment: That was already done in ST:TMP :-)

Comment: @Xantec: That was roughly as hilarious as what I said, yes. :)

Comment: There are probably even more examples of things that *should* have been important in some way, but were promptly forgotten after the episode that featured them.

Comment: Funny thing: "Microbrain" may have been the name given to the indigenous silicon-based life on Velara III (per the Memory Alpha article), but it was also an epithet invoked by Q toward Worf in TNG "Q Who" - "Growl for me, show me that you still care".

Answer (score 10):

Whilst the Exocomps aren't seen again in the TV show they do make an extensive appearance in the Trek Book *[Immortal Coil](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Immortal_Coil)* in which two exocomps (named Winken and Blinken) are key players in a plot to uncover an ancient artificial intelligence. The book states that their civilisation has joined the Federation as full members.

This was later backed up in the [*Star Trek: Online*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Online) MMO game where they were described as being

> "sentient members of the Federation"

...that were strongly aligned to Starfleet and available as members of your crew in both civilian and military modes.

[image: Star Trek Online Exocomps]

Answer (score 9):

*Star Trek: Lower Decks* (which [is canon-ish](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238273/whats-the-canonicity-of-star-trek-lower-decks)) featured an Exocomp who was a member of Starfleet

[image: Exocomp Starfleet]

Comment: "a member of Starfleet" until he ran from the enemy and got left in interstellar space.

Comment: I didn't want to make them look like the jerk they were